# Exit application when a process is in progress

Tags: c#, winforms

When a button is clicked in my form application all other controls are frozen,but if the process is time consuming I want to use a button to exit the application. How can I achieve this? Since all buttons are frozen.

Comment: Have you heard something about threads?

Comment: You may use threading to separate the process thread from the UI thread. You may take this article on threading(http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Comment: If the process is time consuming you need to use the BackgroundWorker like OnesimusUnbound suggests

Comment: you must study the BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). You can run the process without affecting the responsiveness of the UI. Moreover, you may cancel the process.

Referring to the example in the link, put your process logic is in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method, just follow the comment in the sample source code.

Comment: Can u plz explain in detail? with an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: The article provided a [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx#code-snippet-3), you may replace the `ComputeFibonacci` method with your long running process.